# how do i know when to reevalute limits on indefinite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

## A)

$$\int_0^{ln(3)} \frac{e^x}{e^x +2}dx$$

$$u=e^x +2$$ $$du = e^x$$

$$\int_0^{ln(x)} u^{-1}du$$

`when x = ln(3), u = 5`
`when x = 0, u = 3`

$$ln(e^x + 2)]_3^5 = ln|e^5 +2| - ln|e^3+2| = 1.9184629453$$

`without reevaluating limits I get a different answer`

$$ln(e^x + 2)]_0^{ln(3)} = ln|e^{ln(3)}+2| - ln|e^0 + 2| = 0.510825623766$$

`when do I know to reevaluate limits? If I get a different answer for both, which one is correct?`

## B)

$$\int_0^{\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{5}} \frac{arctan(5x)}{1+25x^2}dx$$

$$u=arctan(5x)$$
$$du=\frac{5}{1+25x^2}$$

$$\frac{1}{5}\int_0^{\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{5}}udu$$

`I reevaluated the limits in the integral, because of its form 'udu'`

I'm just confused when to reevaluate the limits, because I know its not always necessary. But doing so shouldn't you end up with the same answer if you didn't? what form does the integral have to take for me to know I have to, or its ok to reevaluate the limits. An answer without too much terminology would be helpful, thanks

what if it takes the form of:

$$\int_3^{ln(9)} e^u du$$

for example?

Comment: You always need to adjust the limits.

Comment: $\bf A)$ When first evaluating the integral with change in the limits, it should be $\int_3^5$. I.e., when $x=0$, $u = e^x +2 = e^0+2= 3$.

Comment: @amWhy corrected, still two different answers with and without reevaluting limits. but still doesnt help answer my question, should I always reevalute the limits like Git Gud said? even if it takes the form like the last integral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices.  You can reevaluate the limits, or you can express the integral in terms of the original variable and use the original limits.  Taking your second example, maybe it helps to show the limits like this:
$$\int_{x=0}^{x=\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{5}} \frac{\arctan(5x)}{1+25x^2}dx$$
$$u=\arctan(5x)$$
$$du=\frac{5}{1+25x^2}$$

$$\frac{1}{5}\int_{x=0}^{x=\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{5}}udu=\frac 15\cdot\left.\frac {u^2}2\right|_{x=0}^{x=\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{5}}$$ 
Now it is clear what our choices are.  One is to reevaluate the limits:
$$\frac 15\left.\frac {u^2}2\right|_{x=0}^{x=\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{5}}=\frac 15\cdot\left.\frac {u^2}2\right|_{u=0}^{u=\frac{-\pi}{3}}=\frac{\pi^2}{90}$$
and the other is to back substitute:
$$\frac 15\left.\frac {u^2}2\right|_{x=0}^{x=\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{5}}=\left.\frac 1{10}(\arctan(5x))^2\right|_{x=0}^{x=\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{5}}=\frac{\pi^2}{90}$$
Depending on the problem, one may be easier than the other.

Comment: ok that clears things up thanks

Comment: I think you forgot 1/5, so it should pi^2/90

Comment: @hit:  you are correct.  Fixed.  Thanks.